# Is there any way to use @next/env in codegen.yaml?

Tags: next.js, graphql-codegen

I was wondering if there was a way to use @next/env to replace variables in `codegen.yaml` when i run `yarn codegen`:

`graphql-codegen -r dotenv/config --config codegen.yml` - this is codegen example to load dot env

`graphql-codegen -r @next/env --config codegen.yml` - this is what i want to achieve

When i call it, i get

`${SERVER_API_URL}/graphql` goes as `undefined/graphql`

My usecase is:

```
# .env
HOST=https
API_DOMAIN=example.com
SERVER_API_URL=$HOST://$API_DOMAIN
```

```
# codegen.yaml
schema: ${SERVER_API_URL}/graphql
```

---

***Why use @next/env?*** it replaces variables in .env, i'm **attaching documentation sample from next.js documentation**:

> Note: Next.js will automatically expand variables ($VAR) inside of
> your .env* files. This allows you to reference other secrets, like so:

```
# .env
HOSTNAME=localhost
PORT=8080
HOST=http://$HOSTNAME:$PORT

If you are trying to use a variable with a $ in the actual value, it needs to be escaped like so: \$.
```

> For example:

```
# .env
A=abc

# becomes "preabc"
WRONG=pre$A

# becomes "pre$A"
CORRECT=pre\$A
```

source: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `@next/env` directly via `-r` flag. However you still have couple of alternatives. For example, you can address the required .env file directly:

`DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env.local graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml -r dotenv/config`

If you still want to use `@next/env`, you can convert your `codegen.yml` to `codegen.js` and import `@next/env`. For example, my original YML:

```
overwrite: true
schema:
  - https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql:
      headers:
        Authorization: 'Bearer ${FAUNA_ADMIN_KEY}'
documents: null
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-graphql-request
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - 'introspection'
```

I re-wrote it as JS:

```
const { loadEnvConfig } = require('@next/env')
loadEnvConfig(process.cwd())

module.exports = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: {
    'https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql': {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.FAUNA_ADMIN_KEY}`,
      },
    },
  },
  documents: null,
  generates: {
    'src/generated/graphql.ts': {
      plugins: [
        'typescript',
        'typescript-operations',
        'typescript-graphql-request',
      ],
    },
    './graphql.schema.json': { plugins: ['introspection'] },
  },
}
```

and then generated the code using `graphql-codegen --config codegen.js`.

Here is an [issue on Github](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/4635) that helped me.